# logging throughout the layers with log4net in .Net

Tags: asp.net, log4net, autofac

I am using Web->Service->Data layer architecture and in order to do some logging with log4net I would need to install to all these three projects. Also I want to decouple the concrete logger in case I would want to change it later in the process. I am using Autofac IOC for injection. Is there a way to add log4net package once and use it between the layers? I found some blog posts about this but there was not much code so I could not get a good grasp on it, you can either give some directions or an explanation of how to achieve this.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

There's a really small assembly which only contains a logging interface, no implementation, that you can use to decouple your assemblies from your logging implementation. It's called ["Common Logging"](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/blob/master/readme.md) [and is available in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging/).

You add a reference to Common.Logging in all your projects that need logging, and then through XML configuration or in your bootstrap code you can inject a concrete logging implementation, such as Log4Net. It also supports other logging frameworks.